# What's the best pattern/strategy for guaranteeing message delivery via SignalR MVC Web application?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm investigating possible existing patterns for helping guarantee message delivery.
I know SignalR is basically fire and forget, but we need to guarantee/ack delivery to client.

We are not (don't want) to use any backend datastore (folks here are concerned with performance). We will not have a super high volume of messages (like a trading app).

The hub is hosted directly in MVC Web app. We don't have to resend messages lost after reconnection (client get's full refresh of data). Current scale out plans for the near future is to have 2 servers behind a load balancer.

I guess another question I have is that when a client sends ACK back to server, will it go to the correct server behind the load balancer?

Thoughts/advice?

Thanks,
JohnB

Comment: I'm interested in the same query.  Did you ever up come with a decent solution?